# OnClientClick = true does not fire server side code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net page which I would like to display a confirmation dialog before a server side event is triggered.

However when the user clicks the OK button, its does not fire the server side event.

I have tried everything that is mentioned in other questions that were posted.

I think the issue could be because I am also using an update panel:

Here is the code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="myUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Hyperlink runat="server" ID="InstanceHyperlink" Visible="false"></asp:Hyperlink><asp:Button runat="server" Visible="false" ID="DeleteInstance" OnClick="DeleteInstance_Click"  Text="Delete Instance"/>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="if ( ! createInstanceConfirm()) { return false; }" OnClick="CreateInstance_Click1" ID="CreateInstance" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Create Instance"></asp:Button>
        </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CreateInstance" EventName="Click"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createInstanceConfirm() 
    {
       UIkit.modal.confirm("You are about to create a new instance", function ()
       { 
           return true; 
       });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are returning `false` but if you don't want to cancel the postback you have to return `true`.

So instead of:

```
OnClientClick="if ( ! createInstanceConfirm()) { return false; }"
```

you could use this (assuming that the method returns either `true` or `false`):

```
OnClientClick="return createInstanceConfirm();"
```

I haven't used this component before but you could try this:

```
function createInstanceConfirm() 
{
   bool confirmed = UIkit.modal.confirm("You are about to create a new instance", function ()
   { 
       return true; 
   });
   return confirmed;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it still does not work, this is driving me mad! I agree it should work.

Comment: @realtek: i haven't used `UIkit.modal.confirm` before. But you have to return true. You can test it by returning true from `createInstanceConfirm` in any case, then the postback takes place. Does `confirm` return anything? Ive edited my answer.

Comment: ok, I just found out the UIKit.modal.confirm actually triggers a callback when the user click OK. So the function is not returning true. It will return instantly. Not sure how I can get this to work now!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the EventName property from the ASyncPostBackTrigger - don't think that's needed. Check the page source once rendered and see what events are linked to the button in question.

Comment: Yes I have removed that but it still doesn't work. If I remove the OnClientClick it works normally, but I need confirmation

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is using callbacks, I managed to get it working by calling another Javascript Function that manually did a post back on the button:

```
  function createInstanceConfirm() {
        return UIkit.modal.confirm("You are about to create a new instance for Development", function () {
            JSFunction();
        });
    }

     function JSFunction() {
             __doPostBack('<%= CreateInstance.ClientID  %>', '');
         }
```

It works the same way as JQuery confirm dialog.